# Discord bot is up but not respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

So, I have the code like this:

[*Sorry, the editor said too much code so I got to move it to codeshare.*](https://codeshare.io/5eZg44)

The bot is up, can receive messages and log to console, BUT, it doesn't log to console that `Logged in!` message, which means the bot is not `ready`, and though the bot can receive command and log it to console, it dose not perform any responds. See log below:

```
2020-07-07T14:39:44.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user *censored*
2020-07-07T14:40:01.359235+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Restarting
2020-07-07T14:40:01.373843+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-07-07T14:40:01.188192+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user *censored*
2020-07-07T14:40:01.188192+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 5ad6fb20 by user *censored*
2020-07-07T14:40:02.483212+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-07-07T14:40:02.587261+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-07-07T14:40:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-07-07T14:40:04.535781+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node .`
2020-07-07T14:40:05.339920+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-07-07T14:40:12.340512+00:00 app[worker.1]:  Iamnoot  nho :   about
```

And this is the screenshot from discord window:

[image: error.png]

Edit: the `Logged in!` message problem was because the state at `client.once('Ready', () => {` must be `ready` :D

Comment: A weird thing is that the code i used is 90% the same from the previous bot, which is running just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many possibilities

1. Your prefix must have a space, otherwise the message content will be " about" and then won't match with the condition.

(line 3, you declared `invite_link`, so why not put it line 10 in your MessageEmbed)

2. You must have in your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node (your file here)"
  },
```

2nd option create a ProcFile file, with

```
node (your file here)
```

and then go to heroku, deploy your changes and go to "Ressources"
[image: heroku]

click on the pen, and enable the worker, click on save and normally it should work